# Encoding problem with UTF-8 while parsing special chars to sendmail

Tags: python

I've have some letters with accents, and I am trying to convert this into a string to be well displayed on an email notification (subject and body), like this:

```
def sent_email_with_warning_notification (subject,email_body):
    try:
        # sample = "bästbonusar.com"
        server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server,587)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(smtp_auth_name,smtp_auth_pass)
        message_structure = 'From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s.\n\n%s.' %(email_sender,email_destination,identifier+' WARNING: '+subject,email_body)
        print (message_structure)
        print (message_structure.encode('utf-8'))
        server.sendmail(email_sender,email_destination,(message_structure.encode('utf-8')))
        server.quit()
    except Exception as e:
        print ('exception set_email_notification> %s' %e)
        server.quit()
        sys.exit(1)
```

but doing this way, instead of receiving for example "bästbonusar.com" will have "bÃ¤stbonusar.com" inside subject and email_body.

So I made another attempt with other accents (latin ones), and out of nowhere, both my latin accents that I used as a test and also that example word, were being well "resolved":

```
message_structure = 'From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s çºaºaâ^^A \n\n%s çºaºaâ^^A' %(email_sender,email_destination,identifier+' WARNING: '+subject,email_body)
```

So my question is, what is the difference between first message_structure variable statement that was not encoding right and the second statement that adding those random chars "çºaºaâ^^A" in the end, start all working even that sample word?

I really don't understand what I am missing here.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't forget [RFC2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047) encoding is *required* for non-ASCII subject lines.